# How do i run validates_presence_of on an instance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to do the following from a library class?

```
class LibClass
  def create_user(provider)
    user = User.new
    if provider == "facebook"
      user.validates_presence_of :email
    else
      # dont validate presence of email
    end
  end
end
```

I am aware that I can do a self.validates_presence_of :email inside the User class, but I am in the library class and am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model, you can create an accessor to toggle the validation on or off.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :validate_email

  def validate_email?; validate_email == true; end

  validates_presenece_of :email, :if => validate_email?
end
```

You can turn the validation on by setting `user.validate_email = true`:

```
def create_user(provider)
  user = User.new
  if provider == "facebook"
    user.validate_email = true
  else
    user.validate_email = false
  end
end
```

To actually get the validations to run, you can call `user.valid?` and the hash `user.errors` will be populated with any validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

validates_presence_of is a class method, not an instance method. In order to do what you want you'll have to do this:

```
user.class_eval {validates_presence_of :email }
```

but the validation will be set on the class, and will be on for all your users.